# Why the Ekeland variational principle needs lower semicontinuity?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I study the Banach space version (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ekeland%27s_variational_principle) for the principle) of the Ekeland variational principle.
It uses lower semicontinuity of $F$ to get its epigraph 
$ epiF=\{(x,t)\in X\times\mathbb{R}: F(x)\le t\}$ is closed and let the diameter of a constructed sequence of sets go to zero.
But I don't know why the closedness is necessary. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: could you provide more information for parts of the proof? otherwise it is hard to answer where closedness is necessary

Comment: In the proof, the closedness is used to prove that the countable intersection of nested, closed balls is non-empty. Without closedness this fails (consider $\cap_n(-1/n,+1/n)$).

Comment: @supinf I tried to find it but it is not easy TT I followed [Banach space theory] by Fabian ch.7.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this example: Define $f:\mathbb R \to \bar{\mathbb R}$ by
$$
F(x)=\begin{cases}\sqrt x& x>0\\
+\infty & x\le 0.\end{cases}
$$
Then $F$ is not lower semicontinuous (at zero). Now take the conditions from the variational principle:
$$
F(u)\le\epsilon, \ F(v)\le F(u), \ F(w)>F(v) - \epsilon|v-w|\ \forall w\ne v.
$$
Let $u$ with $F(u)\le\epsilon$ be given. Let $v>0$.
The third inequality above implies for $w\searrow0$, 
$$
F(v)=\sqrt v\le \epsilon|v|,
$$
which is equivalent to $\sqrt v\ge\epsilon^{-1}$. Together with $F(v)\le F(u)$ this implies $\sqrt u\ge \epsilon^{-1}$.

This implies: for $u$ with $\sqrt u <\epsilon^{-1}$ there is no such $v$ as predicted by the variational principle. Hence the principle fails for not lower semicontinuous functions.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what proof you're looking at, but one way to prove the Ekeland variational principle is to use an argument involving closed, nested sets, similar to lower level sets, whose diameter goes to $0$. Lower semi-continuity is required to make sure the sets are closed.

What is this proof? I actually don't know it! I only know a general thrust of the argument from a brief talk with my supervisor. Essentially, it involves interpreting all of the conditions of the point guaranteed to exist geometrically, and it should turn into an intersection of nested, closed "cones" that intersect with the closed epigraph.

Maybe if you showed the proof where use of lower-semicontinuity is not clear?

Comment: I don't understand that why the closed condition is necessary when we dear with the nested sets whose diameter goes to $0$ reduces to a single point. I think the limiting set (all intersection of the sets) is nonempty even if the original sets are nor closed. Am I wrong here?

Comment: You *do* need the nesting sets to be closed. For example, $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (0, 1/n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the accepted answer so far only provides a counterexample, I though that it would be important to add some light on why the condition is actually necessary.

In the proof of Ekeland's Variational Principle, as you mention, the closedness is used to invoke [Cantor's Intersection Theorem,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem)  which states that a nested sequence of closed sets in a complete metric space whose diameter goes to zero must have a nonempty, singleton intersection. The proof goes as follows: if $\{C_n\}$ is the nested sequence of closed sets and $diam(C_n) \to 0,$ we choose an arbitrary element $x_n \in C_n.$ The condition $$diam(C_n) \to 0$$ will then imply that $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy, and hence convergent to some point $\bar{x}.$ Note that so far we haven't touched the closedness of the $C_n$'s. The problem now is that we can not guarantee that $\bar{x}\in C_n$ for those $C_n$ that are not closed. Therefore, Cantor's Intersection Theorem may fail without this assumption and hence Ekeland's Variational Principle may too.

Hope this helps.